# C# XML reading using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I need to read an **XML file (bigger then 1 GB size)** and load the data into a database. If I use **LINQ** will reading be faster than using an `XmlReader`?

Comment: Google can answer that question for you: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html

Answer (score 2):

`XDocument` (LINQ to XML)  and `XmlDocument` are meant for smaller files, they are so-called DOM parsers. The reason for this is that they load the complete document into the memory and parse it.

`XmlReader` is a [SAX parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) and is meant for big files, because only small chunks are read and the check for well-formedness occurs while reading.

Which files count as "small" and "big" actually depends on certain factors like the installed memory in your machine.

In general, for any decent sized XML file, `XmlReader` should be the fastest solution regarding raw execution time, but it also is by far the hardest API to implement and understand. Especially for novices with this API, the implementation time is significantly higher than with the other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void validateIputXML(string inputXmlPath)
    {

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(inputXmlPath);
        XmlNodeList recipientItem = document.GetElementsByTagName("RECIPIENT");
        foreach (XmlNode childList in recipientItem)
        {
            string attibuteValue_TemplateID = getValue(childList,".//LETTER_HEADER/TEMPLATE_ID");
            string attibuteValue_ProviderName = getValue(childList,".//LETTER_BODY/PROVIDER_INFO/PROVIDER_NAME");
            string attibuteValue_ProviderAddress = getValue(childList,".//LETTER_BODY/PROVIDER_INFO/PROVIDER_ADDRESS1");
            string attibuteValue_ProviderNumber = getValue(childList,".//LETTER_BODY/PROVIDER_INFO/PROVIDERNPI");

            Report.Info(attibuteValue_TemplateID+"-->"+attibuteValue_ProviderName+"-->"+attibuteValue_ProviderAddress+"-->"+attibuteValue_ProviderNumber);
        }
    }


    public string getValue(XmlNode Xnode, string attributeName)
    {
        XmlNode innerNode = Xnode.SelectSingleNode(attributeName);
        string attributeValue = innerNode.InnerText;
        return attributeValue;
    }
```